# How can I delete columns of RDD using an if statement in spark (using scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, rdd

Suppose I have a text file where each entry has a couple hundred data points. I want to get rid of any column which has a question mark- using the drop function and picking it out seems tedious; is there a faster way?

Something like `dataframe.map( x => ifcontainsquestionmarkdropcolumn(x))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Number of question marks in each column can be calculated with "sum" function, and columns where number is non-zero can be dropped:

```
val df = Seq(("nomark", "question?mark"))
  .toDF("expected", "dropped")

val questionCountColumns = df
  .columns
  .map(c => sum(when(col(c).contains("?"), 1).otherwise(0)).alias(c))

val questionCountRow = df.select(questionCountColumns: _*).first()

val columnsToDrop = df
  .columns
  .filter(c => questionCountRow.getAs[Long](c) > 0)

val result = df.drop(columnsToDrop: _*)
```

Result is:

```
+--------+
|expected|
+--------+
|nomark  |
+--------+
```